# Change view css based on field value?

Tags: views

the view shows a simple article, i want to show the view in rtl direction if a specific field value is YES for example, if the value is NO, then the view will be displayed as ltr.

I have a hidden field that have two values, Yes or No, based on them i need to change the VIEW. only the view, everything else in the page must stay the same.

How to achieve that please

Answer (score 1):

It is easily achievable with drupal_add_css in a hook_preprocess_views_view.

[An example of it can be found in the last comment here.](https://www.drupal.org/node/954262)